# Update List after deleting an element

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a project generated with JHipster 5.5.0 and I have 2 entities: parent & child.

I list the children when I see the details of the parent. When I want to delete a child, I use the child's modal and it works as it should be.

My issue is after deleting the entity the list is not being updated and I don't know where to look. I tried using static methods so I can reload the list but I'm unable to do so. Any help will be appreciated.

Child's Angular code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { JhiEventManager } from 'ng-jhipster';

import { IChild } from 'app/shared/model/child.model';
import { ChildService } from './Child.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-child-delete-dialog',
    templateUrl: './child-delete-dialog.component.html'
})
export class ChildDeleteDialogComponent {
    child: IChild;

    constructor(
        private childService: ChildService,
        public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
        private eventManager: JhiEventManager
    ) {}

    clear() {
        this.activeModal.dismiss('cancel');
    }

    confirmDelete(id: number) {
        this.childService.delete(id).subscribe(response => {
            this.eventManager.broadcast({
                name: 'childtModification',
                content: 'Deleted a child'
            });
            this.activeModal.dismiss(true);
        });
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-child-delete-popup',
    template: ''
})
export class ChildDeletePopupComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private ngbModalRef: NgbModalRef;

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private modalService: NgbModal) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ child }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.ngbModalRef = this.modalService.open(ChildDeleteDialogComponent as Component, {
                    size: 'lg',
                    backdrop: 'static'
                });
                this.ngbModalRef.componentInstance.child = child;
                this.ngbModalRef.result.then(
                    result => {
                        this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popup: null } }], { replaceUrl: true, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
                        this.ngbModalRef = null;
                    },
                    reason => {
                        this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popup: null } }], { replaceUrl: true, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
                        this.ngbModalRef = null;
                    }
                );
            }, 0);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngbModalRef = null;
    }
}
```

In the parent entity, I have a button like this:

```
<button type="submit" [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { popup: 'child/'+ child.id + '/delete'} }]"
replaceUrl="true"
queryParamsHandling="merge"
class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
<fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
<span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.delete">Delete</span>
</button>
```

The modal neither the component that deletes the child have not been modified.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: JHipster includes an event system to manage this kind of situations.
It works by broadcasting a message after deletion to the subscribed components, the child list here, to make it reload data. 
This should work as is so as Vivek said you should share code in order to get some help

Comment: I just added the most significant code, otherwise, it's just vanilla. About the broadcasting message, how could I sent it to the parent module so it reloads the list?

Comment: Well this should already work since you seem to not have touched the generated code. 

Btw,  `name: 'childtModification'` seems wrong, this should be `childModification`. Maybe you can try this and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for the same answer:

When deleting a child, the component broadcasts the event like this:

```
this.eventManager.broadcast({
    name: 'childListModification',
    content: 'Deleted a Child'
});
```

I only had to subscribe (in the parent component) to the event like this:

```
registerChangeInChildren() {
    this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('childListModification', response => {
        this.getAll();
    });
}
```

and call `this.registerChangeInChildren()` in `ngOnInit()` and everything works as spected.